# Animating scale of Inflow object doesn’t work

Tags: fluid-simulation, mantaflow

I'm trying to make fluid slowly become a trickle and then stop (ie not animate the "Use Flow" button). I'm a mid level user of fluid simulations.

So following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MqFF0keVmCY&ab_channel=BlenderSecrets I see you have to animate the scale of the Inflow object over time. But I did that with my file and the flow doesn't change (even though I used a tiny scale).

Here is my file https://pasteall.org/media/e/e/ee86d1421f3a68010d64dba204bc6821.blend if you want to check it out (from frames 1980 - 2080, since I use this in another large scene).

Have I missed something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: UHM....don't know whether you have your own renderfarm with hundreds of servers, but you have a resolution of 600 with 31x21x8 m....to be honest: try this on a simply and easy to bake project. This should work. But i would not try this for the first time on such a massive project...just for fun i tried to bake 2 frames...needed 2 minutes -nobody wants to wait that long just to help you. (ok, i don't want to, maybe others are more patient)

Answer (score 0):

I just tried out with default cube, added quick liquid and changed the flow behaviour from geometry to inflow.

Then i keyframed the scale of it and got:

[image]

So yes, this works. Why yours doesn't work - i don't know and because i don't want to bake yours for 2 hours (maybe the resolution is even too low? -> because your inflow is already tiny and you scale it down even more), i cannot help more. But maybe you also try it with default cube and quick liquid yourself, if this works and you did the same to your big project, i would guess that it might be your resolution.

Comment: Ok thanks, it's actually for a re-enactment animation of a pipe bursting at a factory, so the pipe was pretty big and wanted to keep real world dimensions.